# Request Location permission at runtime not working

Tags: android

I have wrote my code from [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). The `askForPermission()` method is called when a button is clicked. But every time I click on the button it displays the else part, I mean `Permission denied`. What I am doing wrong here. How to open the pop up for requesting permission. And after granting permission how can I display the `latitude` and `longitude` in a TOAST message. ?? I am new in android and I will be very thankful if anyone can solve it.

I have tried enabling `LOCATION` permission from the `mobile's setting` page for my application. But still when I click on the button it displays `PERMISSION DENIED`

> events.java

```
package com.example.borntoflirt.design1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class events extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button getLocationBtn;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        getLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLocation);

        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //First of All check for permission .
                askForPermission();
            }
        });

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    private void askForPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have permission in manifest?

Comment: Ohh shit. I have set for the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, not for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. For your smartness I am at least able to see the popup asking for permission. I am struggling for 3 days. Now I will try how can I access `latitue` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for your question in comment. So to access location and latitude and longitude you need to implement couple interfaces in your activity class:
`implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener`

Then override necessary methods. In `onConnected` method make request to location either using deprecated `FusedLocationApi` which still works or new  `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Also you will get `onLocationChanged` method with parameter `Location` there you can access the latitude and longitude using `location.getLatitude();` and `location.getLongitude();`

You will also have to make connection to `GoogleApiClient` for example:

`protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }`

Handle removing location updates in `onPause` and making request again in `onResume`